# How to achieve the last letter without letter-spacing in a text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Dear community members,

I have a small problem, which involves a text input field with letter-spacing. For example the following code:

`<input type="text" style="letter-spacing:1em; text-align:center;" maxlength="6" id="code" name="code" />`

This would cause the text not center properly due to the last letter-spacing at the last letter. Are there alternative methods in which I can achieve spacing, but also text centering capabilities? All solutions are appreciated (incl. javascript and JQuery).

(The user enters a string of 6 characters long, with no spaces.)

Thanks for the response!

PS: I do not think that I forgot any relevant code, because the em can also be replace with 10px. I have a screenshot here: http://www2.picturepush.com/photo/a/7889005/640/7889005.png

Comment: not nearly enough information here to understand the issue.

Comment: It looks pretty well centred in Chromium/Ubuntu...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about adding a `padding-left` of `1em`?

```
<input type="text" style="letter-spacing:1em; text-align:center; padding-left: 1em" maxlength="6" id="code" name="code" />
```

Here is an example, with the `maxlength` removed and a width added, so you can see that it is centered properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jgm42/

Note:  This looks to only be an issue with some browsers.  IE, shockingly, seems to correctly leave off the extra spacing unless there is an adjacent character.  You might have to do some browser-specific code.

Comment: jeffb beat me to it, so here's the fiddle I was creating anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/VZm96/

Comment: Oh great, it works! Thanks! However the blinking line, is not standing still next to the last letter, but still with a spacing. I think I should accept that fact (or is it possible to achieve it?).

Comment: At the moment, the only other solution that comes to mind is adding the extra spacing with javascript/jQuery, but that solution will have **far** more issues and annoyances than this.